Formula for Regression with ARIMA (1, 0, 0) X (1, 0, 0) Errors?
I am trying to figure out how the Arima calculations work, and can someone confirm I am interpreting the formula for a regression model with Arima (1, 0, 0)X(1, 0, 0) correctly?
The specification for this model calls for an autoregressive error term as well as a seasonal autoregressive error term (note: this is quarterly data). Also, let's assume there's one independent variable and an intercept. With that being said, I would think the formula for this type of regression would be:
$\hat{Y} = \beta{_0} + \beta{X_1} + (ar1)*e_{t-1} + (sar1)*e_{t-4}$
Is this correct? My manual calculations are slightly off from what R is generating, so I think I'm missing something...

See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/

I figured it out! The seasonal component of the model follows the form of the non-seasonal component. As a result, it must also account for (i.e., remove) the autoregressive error term from the seasonal component. So the formula is actually:
$\hat{Y} =\beta{_0} + \beta{X_1} + (ar1)*e_{t-1} + ((sar1)*e_{t-4} -(ar1)*(sar1)*e_{t-5})$
I figured I'd keep the question up in case others find it helpful

Hi Amy: I see what you're doing and I think it's close. (It's been too long so I take this with a grain of salt ).  One thing is  that I'm pretty sure that  $\hat{Y}$ should be given a t subscript. Also, should there not  be an $e_{t}$ on the RHS ? For the seasonal part, I see what you're doing with the $e_{t-5}$ but that's going to cause non-linearity. So, that should probably be reformulated as one unknown. Check out Box, Jenkins and Reinsel for how to do this for sure. There's a famous seasonal case study that BJR uses with airline passenger data.  So, hopefully they explain it there.
